# Hardware for Monero mining hash rate of 1 MH/s

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, mining-hardware

I checked in crypto compare calculator about hash power required for profitable Monero mining. It showed that 1MH/s is required to earn 0.5174 XMR or $86.18 per day

I checked Monero benchmarks and found the max hash rate offered by AMD THREADRIPPER 3990X is 64000 H/s or 64 KH/s

Is there any hardware capable of providing 1 MH/s for Monero mining?

If I assemble the hardware myself, what specification will give me a 1 MH/s for Monero mining?

Thanks in advance

Comment: il va te falloir 10 cpu AMD de dernière génération pour obtenir 1mh/s ca demande un investissement énorme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Someone achieved 100kH/s https://xmrig.com/benchmark/4nmg1G and that really is the highest we know so far.

Comment: That gives very small profits per day. I don't think that's worth the effort

Answer (score 0):

Good gain. I'm upgrading my mining station. It's a good parameter to a new one.

CPUID, 830F10 / Family: 17 / Model: 31 / Stepping: 0. Memory, 4 x 8GB DDR4 @ 3200Mhz CL 13-12-14-27
AMD EPYC 7H12 - 100-000000055 / 100-100000055WOF

Good start.